# Use custom environment vars for os.path.expandpath in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

It seems as if Python's [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) function operates on the calling process environment. Is there a way to add my own new variables into the mix *without* polluting the process environment?

Best I can come up with ad hoc is:

```
>>> env = os.environ
>>> env["FOO"] = "VAL"
>>> os.path.expandvars("variable FOO=$FOO")
'variable FOO=VAL'
>>> del env["FOO"]
```

Ideally I'd like to pass an `env` argument like the one for [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). It seems that I'd have to write such a wrapper myself?

Answer (score 1):

It may seem silly but try doing the following:

```
# Crete a new env and modify it
new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env["FOO_VAR"] = "FOO_VALUE" 

# Replace the env e use expandvars
tmp_env = os.environ
os.environ = new_env
print(os.path.expandvars("variable FOO=$FOO_VAR"))

# Return to the old env
os.environ = tmp_env
```

By the way, I initially was using regex to identify both %(?.+)% and $\{?(?.+)\}?[/\\\n], but doing the above seems better.